# Drag and drop to open files

Tags: python, drag-and-drop

What I'm referring to is how, say, an image editor can automatically open a file if that file is dropped onto the program's icon. Now, I'm not developing an image editor, but I am reading input from a file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you referring to dropped onto the program's icon in Explorer/Finder/Nautilus/etc.? Or onto the icon of the already-running program on the Taskbar/Dock/whatever?

Comment: Also, are you building a GUI app? If so, which GUI framework are you using? Most of the third-party ones have nice wrappers to make this easy, but Tkinter doesn't.

Comment: The former (explorer, nautilus, finder). And, no. There is no GUI - it simply takes a file and creates an output file.

Comment: May I ask why this is put on hold? Besides the fact that I'd accepted an answer before it got on hold (making putting it on hold kind of ridiculous), what kind of attempted solution could I have possibly tried? I have minimal experience with Python - until earlier the day I posted the question, I'd never even attempted to open a file at all.

Comment: What kind of thing could I have possibly tried? I knew that nothing I actually knew how to do would accomplish it, and I didn't know what library to look in.

Comment: Also - I basically asked for one line of code. It wasn't like I was asking someone to write some complicated algorithm - I was asking for information I didn't know. Seems pretty legit.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but it's possible that people closed this question because they assumed you were asking the more complicated question, and therefore there is research you could have done. In general, when your question is ambiguous, don't just clarify in comments; edit the question until it's something that future readers with similar problems, and Google's text search engine, and drive-by voters, are all likely to understand immediately. (Even if I'm wrong about the reason, and that wouldn't have helped you here, it's still usually good advice.)

Comment: It's been a while since I found this out (thanks, by the way), but I am curious about one thing. You said "they assumed you were[...]" and also said that there were two possible things I could be asking.

Comment: I specifically asked about the program's icon. Maybe I'm mistaken, but isn't that phrase enough to distinguish between the two? And, if not, is there a simple phrase like that that would?

Comment: I think the problem is that you're thinking in Windows-specific terms, but never mentioned Windows anywhere. For example, on OS X, the thing on the Dock that looks and acts like an icon is called an icon. The fact that Windows doesn't use that word for the things on the taskbar that look and act like icons is a quirk of Windows. If you only care about Windows, say that somewhere in your question, and then you can use terms in their Windows-specific meaning and nobody will get confused.

Comment: Oh, see I didn't know that. I just assumed that icon, as I was using it, was standard / os-neutral. I guess it's best to mention as much information as possible, even if it doesn't seem relevant. Thanks, again.

Comment: No problem. Another thing for future reference: If you're building a GUI app, mention which GUI framework you're using. For example, Qt has its own drag&drop abstractions that it maps to each desktop system in the appropriate way, so with PyQt/PySide you can just think in Qt terms, while with Tkinter you have to think in terms of each platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different things you could mean here.

---

First, you could be dragging a file onto the program's executable file. For example, I open my home directory in one window, and /usr/local/bin in another, and drag spam.txt from the left window and drop it on myprogram in the right.

In theory, what happens here is entirely up to the file manager. However, most file managers—including Windows Explorer and OS X Finder and the default things that come with most of the popular linux distros—will do the exact same thing: just run the program, as if you had typed this at a shell:

```
"/usr/local/bin/myprogram" "/home/kevinmills/spam.txt"
```

So, from inside `myprogram`, you just need to look at [`sys.argv[1:]`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) for the list of files, and it will work the same way whether they were supplied on the command line or by drag and drop.

If you drag a file to a symlink, Windows shortcut, or Mac alias to the program's executable file stored somewhere else, like on your desktop, effectively the same thing happens, and you don't have to worry about the differences.

If you've built an application bundle for OS X instead of just a flat script, things are more complicated. However, all of the simpler wrappers that would have let you build such a bundle without knowing what you're doing should automatically take care of the magic that makes it look the same as a flat script, so you shouldn't have to worry about that.

---

Alternatively, you could be asking about dropping a file on some kind of representation of your already-running program on a dock or taskbar or the like.

That's more complicated. And it's different for each platform. But fortunately, that's not what you're doing.

Comment: Haven't actually gotten to try this out, but from what I can tell, sys.argv seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks.